# Golden Rectangle where width is equal to 2 units

Tags: quadratics, golden-ratio

[Question reads: Commencing with a square ABCD of side length 2 units, locate E, the midpoint of DC. With centre E and radius EB draw an arc to intersect DC produced at Y. At Y construct YX perpendicular to DY to meet AB produced at X.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmCBp.png)

a) Show that rectangle AXYD is Golden, and,
b) Show that rectangle BXYC is also Golden

I've been working on this question on and off for what feels like a few hours and I can't get beyond the first question. I've attempted to use the following proportion:

YC:CD = YD:YC

to yield proof that the length of the rectangle follows the golden ratio, but I've found myself stuck.

I'm at the point where I can say that the length of the rectangle is equal to (2+2√5)/2, or twice that of Phi. Is that sufficient proof to deem that sides AX and DY follow the golden ratio, as they are equal to the width of the rectangle * Phi?

And for question 2, would I be using a similar strategy to prove that the rectangle BXYC is also Golden? If not, where would I begin?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the length of the rectangle is $AX=\frac{2+2\sqrt{5}}{2}=1+\sqrt{5}$.

So $\frac{AX}{AD}=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$, the golden ratio.

For Question 2, as $BX=\sqrt{5}-1$, we just have to show that $\frac{BC}{BX}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}-1}$ is equal to $\phi$, and it is not difficult.